# Render a partial view with an IEnumerable as a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to render a partial view with a list of news received from a rss feed.
I have the following controller :

**RssFeedPartial**

```
public ActionResult HealthCareNews()
{
// get the news add them to a list.
return PartialView("_HealthCareNews",rssList);
}
```

i want to render this partial view in the About, News, etc pages.

**Home Controller**

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

**About page**

```
<div id="rightColumn">
@Html.Partial("_HealthCareNews")
 </div>
```

**_HealthCareNews page**

```
@model IEnumerable<MDISS.ViewModel.RSS>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
//display list
}
```

When i try to open the **About** Page, I get the following error :

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Use `@Html.Action("HealthCareNews")` instead of `@Html.Partial`

Comment: i tried and it does not work

Comment: Does `HealthCareNews` action belongs to `HomeController`? If not, you have to specify the controller name: `@Html.Action("HealthCareNews", "ControllerNameOfThisAction")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Html.Partial("_HealthCareNews")` directly renders your partial view. Since you are not passing it any data, the `Model` property will be `null`. This gives the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

Instead you want to call the `HealthCareNews` action on your controller. You can do this by using  [Html.Action](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/Q8V2130113-RenderPartial-vs-RenderAction-vs-Partial-vs-Action-in-MVC-Razor.html) like this:

```
@Html.Action("HealthCareNews")
```

Directly rendering a partial view (with `Html.Partial`) can be used when you pass the data directly from your view or when the partial view only contains static data.

When your partial view depends on data that's not part of the model of the view your rendering it from, you can use `Html.Action`. That way, you execute the action method on your controller. The action method can build the model that's required for your partial view.

### Update

An action method in MVC returns an `ActionResult`. `ActionResult` is an abstract base class for all the different types of `ActionResult`s that exist in MVC like `ViewResult`, `JsonResult` and `PartialViewResult`. Some developers prefer to have ActionResult as the return type for all their methods. Others try to declare the most specific return type. I prefer to use the latter. Especially when unit testing this makes the code easier to use because you can work with the result directly.

The difference between `ViewResult` and `PartialViewResult` has to do with using a Layout page. Since a PartialView is used for returning a single piece of HTML that can be embedded in another page, you don't want to use a layout page. A `ViewResult` returns a complete view with options to use a layout page.

Comment: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'. I changed to action, and this is the error i get.

Comment: This error sometimes happens when there is a parser error on your page. Especially when you have a line break after the @ character. Can you verify this is not the case?

Comment: this is not the case, btw should my Controller return a View instead of a PartialView ?

Comment: i don't know what extra info to give you. I tried the answers above, and they do not work. @Html.Action does not work

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace and exception details?

Comment: I solved it. what i did was used `@Html.Action(actionName,controllerName)`. Then i moved the partial view in the Views/Shared folder and it worked.

Comment: Can you tell me the difference of using `PartialViewResult` or `ActionResult` for a method ?

Comment: @user2287957 I added an update to the post. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing the error because you are not passing the expected `IEnumerable<MDISS.ViewModel.RSS>` model to the `"_HealthCareNews"` partial view:

```
<div id="rightColumn">
    @Html.Partial("_HealthCareNews" /*Model required here*/)
</div>
```

You *could* use one of the following:

`@Html.RenderAction("HealthCareNews")`

`@Html.Action("HealthCareNews")`

These methods will call the `HealthCareNews` controller action that you have created, which correctly loads the `"_HealthCareNews"` partial view with the appropriate `rssList` model.

*However*

I personally prefer calling partials from within my razor view, passing in any required model from my view model.  Using your example this might look like:

**ViewModel**

```
public class AboutPageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MDISS.ViewModel.RSS> RssList { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult About()
{ 
    return View(new AboutPageViewModel { RssList = rssList });
}
```

**Razor View**

```
@model AboutPageViewModel

<div id="rightColumn">
    @Html.Partial("_HealthCareNews", Model.RssList)
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the following `@Html.Partial("_HealthCareNews", new Ienumerable<MDISS.ViewModel.RSS>)` and i receive the following error : can not create an instance of the abstract class or interface Ienumerable<>.

Comment: That's because `IEnumerable<>` is an interface, you cannot create an instance of an interface.  Try `List<MDISS.ViewModel.RSS>`.

Comment: Now the about page loads, but the partial one does not

Comment: With an *empty* collection of `RSS` objects, would you expect the partial view to output any HTML?  Looking at your example, it looks like it wouldn't.